# Reliable ways to register a user's computer with a server

Tags: security, session, authentication

As part of strengthening session authentication security for a site that I am building, I am trying to compile a list of the best ways to register a user's computer as a second tier of validation - that is in addition to the standard username/password login, of course.  Typical ways of registering a user's computer are by setting a cookie and or IP address validation.  As prevalent as mobile computing is, IP mapping is less and less a  reliable identifier.  Security settings and internet security & system optimization software can make it difficult to keep a cookie in place for very long.

Are there any other methods that can be used for establishing a more reliable computer registration that doesn't require the user to add exceptions to the various cookie deleting software?

Comment: "Big List" questions are off-topic here.  Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: How is this more secure?I mean if you want authentication of a user how do you expect to get it by registering the PC?You don't know who is using the registered PC in any case.That is why you request user credentials

Comment: Yes, that is why I indicated "that is in addition to the standard username/password login, of course."

Comment: @davmorr:You missread my comment.I am not asking if this is more secure.I am saying it is not.By authenticating the PC you are doing nothing since you have no idea who is actually using it

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do device authentication, you may want to consider mutually authenticated SSL. Here, you'd deploy a client identity certificate to each endpoint you'd want to authenticate. Then, you set the server up to require client authentication, so that a client would need to present a valid identity certificate in order to form the SSL tunnel.

This, of course, is not a perfect solution. In reality, this presents much of the same weaknesses as other solutions (to various degrees) Once your client identity certificates go to your clients, they are out of your control; should a client give their certificate to anyone else, you lost the device authentication that you have based on it. SSL identity certificates are generally stored in a keystore on the client which is encrypted with a password or other credential needed to unlock them. While a client certificate could still be compromised, it's somewhat stronger that just a cookie or something like that (assuming you don't have a client that is trying to give away its credential). In addition, you'd want to come up with some validation routine that a client would need to go though in order to get a credential in the first place (how do I know that this is a client device that I *want* to remember/register?).

Remember, these types of approaches only do *device* authentication, not users. There are more in-depth schemes already developed for device authentication than what I've mentioned; for example, 802.1x is a network protocol where an endpoint needs to present a client-side certificate to the network switch to get on a LAN. This is out-of-scope for a web application scenario, like what you've described, but the idea is the same (put a cryptographic credential on the client and validate it to establish the connection).

This, like all other security matters really, is a risk decision. What are you trying to accomplish with such a countermeasure? What are the threats you're trying to prevent and what are the consequences if someone does log in on an unregistered device? Only your situation can answer those questions and let you see the real risk, if you need/should mitigate it, and, if so, how strong of a solution do you need to get the risk level down to an acceptable level?

Comment: The problem with the client authentication isn't that the client cerficates can be passed out (this can be addressed by issuing the certificate to specific IPs/DNs) but how will the client certificate be deployed/install to clients in the first place.If we are talking about thousands or even hundrend of devices this is impossible

Comment: Your suggestion for the SSL identity certificate looks like the solid option, thanks for the feedback.  Basically, we are trying to provide solution options for two-factor login authentication. The obvious go-to would be something like CAC cards (smart cards), which some of the authors and editors on-site will own, but not necessarily all.  We are exploring alternatives that, though not as secure, would allow for alternative user validation for access which would have a more limited scope of editorial and workflow permissions once the user is successfully logged in. I think we are set, thanks!

Comment: In this case, I think the SSL client auth mechanism makes a lot of sense. It's not as strong as a physical token, but for lower-risk-scenarios (which seem to match what you describe), it's appropriate.

Comment: @davmorr:The smart cart solution though, authenticates the user to the PC and not your server.

Comment: Yep, @user384706 is right (as pointed out above, as well). Smartcards/one-time-password-devices/etc are used as multifactor authentication *for the user*, resulting in a strong degree of confidence as to the actual person sitting at the endpoint. Mutually-auth SSL authenticates the client (the endpoint, or, really, something running on the endpoint with access to the keystore). Both of these can be valuable, and both as valid to your usecase, but they are different things.

Answer (score 0):

> the best ways to register a user's computer as a second tier of
>   validation

From my point of view this approach does not offer much in the *aspect of authentication*.
You are not authenticating a user and have no idea who is using the PC that you would accept as being registered.

The way you describe it, this step should be a configuration **rule in the firewall** to accept connections from specific IPs only.

IMO the filtering of the PCs is the responsibility of a firewall and it would be much better handled by the firewall than any application level filtering.
Just think that you would have the overhead in *your application* to examine each request and decide whether to accept it or not.
Better leave this preprocessing overhead to the firewall. That's why it is there.